# Python requests: How to PUT a string in body?

Tags: python, http, rest, python-requests

I need to PUT data from a string (no dict) as the body of the call to a REST API.
When I call

```
r = requests.put(url, data = string)
```

then I can see in `r.request.body` after this call that it is `None`. Also, the server responds with a "411 Length Required" error.

However, when I try it with a dict instead of a string then it works, as the server responds with the correct JSON data. Moreover, in that case I can see in `r.request.body` the correct data.

Any ideas?

PS: I am using Python 2.7.3 and Python-requests 1.2.0

Comment: You mean `r = requests.put(url, data = string)`? Or something different? Because as written, you're going to get an exception saying that modules aren't callable.

Comment: requests `post` automatically `There are many times that you want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data will be posted directly`, perhaps this holds true for `put` request too.  Plus I believe when you check `r.body` it is the response body, not your request body

Comment: Now that you've fixed this… `requests.put` returns a `Response` object, which doesn't have a `body` attribute. So, what are you actually looking at here? Is it `r.request.body`? If so, are you sure there were no redirects between the request and the response? More importantly, is the _server_ recording no request data? (In other words, is the problem that you can't send a body, or just that you don't know how to figure out what you sent after the fact?)

Comment: @ abarnert: yes indeed, sorry, I have updated my posting.
@ dm03514: No, I check the body of the request. I know because when I try it with a dictionary as PUT body data then I can see the correct values in the request's body. However, I can't use a dictionary so I need to use a string.

Comment: You updated it to fix the first problem, but not the second one. Your question is still meaningless as it stands.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, I am looking at `r.request.body`. I think there is a redirect. When I call the API using a dict as body data, then the call to the API succeeds (I get the correct JSON data back from the server). However, when I use a string instead of the dict then I get a "411 Length Required" error back from the server, which indicates to me that it has not received any data in the body. This is also shown when I check the headers of the request in `r`.

Comment: @Matthias: If there is a redirect, then `r.request.body` is probably not what you want; try `r.history[-1].body`.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for the info. It seems there is indeed a redirect, but with `r.history[-1].body` it does not work, as there is only one element in `history`. And `r.history.text` gives me "302 Found". But interestingly it works fine when using a dict, as said.

Comment: First, do you mean "it does not work, as there is only one element in history"? Sure, `r.history` probably only has one element in it, but it's still a list, and `h[-1]` returns the last element even if there's only one.

Comment: Second, the fact that the `text` in the last history request is `302 Found` is a very good sign that it was a redirect, but really, you should be looking at `h.status_code` to see that it's a 301 or 302, not trying to parse the text.

Comment: What `Content-Type` does the server expect? Is `string` x-www-form-urlencoded? The analog of `requests.put(url, data={'k':'v'})` is `requests.put(url, data='k=v', headers={'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks, after trying out a few things I found exactly that as well. So your comment would have been exactly the correct answer to this question +1

Comment: @Matthias: I'm a bit confused here. If the server was expecting form-encoded content, why did you say "now the content has to be a string"? Also, if your actual question was "Why is the server rejecting my request?", why did you ask "Why can't I find the body I submitted with my request?"

Comment: @abarnert: The content is stored in a string, because server expects a body like "default=xyz&default=abc", so I would need a dict with multiple instances of the same key. Before messing around with a custom dict class that would simulate such a thing, I decided that a simple string would be much easier. And I asked the way I did because I was not sure what exactly the problem was. I was guessing due to my lack of experience here.

Comment: OK, now I understand. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) twice over: first you said "I need to send a string" instead of "I need to send multiple instances of the same key, and I don't know how to do that other than by sending a string", and then you asked for help debugging a piece of your unseen implementation instead of asking how to do what you're trying to do. That's why it took you hours of waiting, and a dozen or more responses and clarifications, to get the answers you needed. But at least you got them, so… could be worse…

Comment: @abarnert: You're right, thanks for the link to the XY problem :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even after three attempts to clarify the question, it still isn't clear what you're asking here, but I can try to throw out enough info that you can figure out the answer.

First, `r = requests.put(url, data = string)` returns a `Response`, which doesn't have a `body`, but it does have a `request`, and a `history` of 0 or more redirect requests, all of which are `PreparedRequest` objects, which do have `body` attributes.

On the other hand, if you did `r.requests.Request(method='PUT', url=url, data=string)`, that would return a `Request`, which has to be `prepare()`d before it has a body.

Either way, if I do a simple test and look at the results, I find that the `body` is always correct:

```
>>> resp = requests.put('http://localhost/nosuchurl', data='abc')
>>> resp.request.body
'abc'
>>> resp = requests.put('http://localhost/redirect_to_https', data='abc')
>>> resp.history[-1].request.body
'abc'
>>> req = requests.Request(method='PUT', url='http://localhost/nosuchurl', data='abc')
>>> preq = req.prepare()
>>> preq.body
'abc'
```

My best guess is that you need to be looking at `resp.history[0].request.body`, but you're looking at `resp.request.body`, or something similar.

If [Redirection and History](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) in the quickstart tutorial doesn't help, read the detailed API docs, or just experiment with all of them until you figure it out.

Or do this:

```
resp = request.put('http://localhost/nosuchurl', data='abc', allow_redirects=False)
```

And then do the redirect-handling manually.

Comment: I am indeed looking at `r.request.body`. I can see the correct data here if I am using a dict instead of a string. I have updated the original question accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry that I could not explain my problem better. I guess this is due to the fact that I simply do not know enough about this topic. But following your explainations I found that of course you're right, there is a redirect and I have to check the `history` of `r`. I will see what else could be the problem in my case then. Thanks.